# How to compile to avoid shared library errors?

Tags: mysql, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I need to develop a program using MySQL C API. I will develop it on my CentOS virtual machine and run it on RedHat servers. I compiled a some kind of Hello World program and transferred it to the server. But I get an error about shared libraries.

```
$ ./test1
./test1: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I see that this library exists but with a slightly different name:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/libssl*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 458752 Aug 13 17:27 /usr/lib/libssl.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     26 Sep 14 01:26 /usr/lib/libssl.so -> ../../lib/libssl.so.0.9.8er
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 217560 Nov  9 12:22 /usr/lib/libssl3.so
```

Since I am not root on the server, I can't simply make a symbolic link. I will distribute my program to many people without root privilege and system administration skills. Is there a safe way of compiling my program to avoid such errors?

here is my simple program:

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());
}
```

and, this is how I compiled it:

```
gcc version.c -o version  `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

output of ldd ./test1:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00685000)
libmysqlclient.so.16 => /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16 (0x00a8c000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x00110000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00240000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/libnsl.so.1 (0x002b7000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00f5a000)
libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib/libssl.so.10 (0x00e0c000)
libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10 (0x002d1000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x004d3000)
libfreebl3.so => /lib/libfreebl3.so (0x00686000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00977000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x006ea000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /lib/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00123000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00804000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x001f4000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/libresolv.so.2 (0x0021b000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00dbf000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00234000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00f0b000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00e72000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0x00862000)
```

output of mysql_config --cflags --libs:

```
-I/usr/include/mysql  -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fPIC   -DUNIV_LINUX
-rdynamic -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient -lz -lcrypt -lnsl -lm -lssl -lcrypto
```

Comment: what does your `mysql_config --cflags --libs` say? What does `ldd ./test1` say?

Comment: @unbeli: I added it to the question for better readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binary is compiled against openssl version 1.0.x and therefore requires openssl major version 1. The target machine has version 0.9.8, which is major version 0. Different major versions are considered incompatible, hence the error.

Comment: I don't know which version is installed on each server. Is there a way of making a "one size fits all" binary? static linking, or etc.?

Comment: Static linking would work. If you don't want full static linking, you can go through the ldd list and select the libraries that might be absent and/or different versions on the target machines.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, static linking of Linux binaries generally does *not* work. Any binary that uses `getpwnam` will, emit a warning if linked statically, and will likely crash if run on a system with a different version of glibc installed.

Comment: @EmployedRussian so, how do people distribute their programs?

Comment: Can I bundle the set of libraries I use with my program and send them all together?

Comment: you don't need to make statically linked binary. Just link statically the libraries you aren't sure about like openssl

Answer (score 2):

Read up on `ld.so` and its variables such as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_PRELOAD`-- you can install, say `libssl.so` in your own `~/lib/` and have the dynamic linker find that.

Needless to say, you are much better off doing this via the package management system.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand you. Can you please explain a bit more?